# ¿Cómo diferenciar dos instancias de la misma clase en Java?

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, object

Tengo lo siguiente: en un sistema, se desea saber si, cada vez que se ejecuta la función, se utiliza la misma instancia `java.util.ArrayList`, o utiliza una nueva por cada ejecución.

La línea de código es:

```
private final List<MakeModel> _collection = new ArrayList<MakeModel>()
```

Utilizando el método `hashCode()`, todas las instancias de `ArrayList` que se inicialicen tienen el mismo resultado: todos retornan 1. Entonces, ¿hay alguna forma de diferenciar una instancia `ArrayList` vacía de otra instancia `ArrayList`?

Comment: ya probaste con == ya que compara las referencias del objeto o con instanceof

Comment: Ya probé. Si instancio dos objetos ArrayList, el resultado es "true"

Comment: Y como instancias los dos objetos?

Comment: Muestra más código, que lo que comentas no nos cuadra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes ocupar una función que compare las listas que necesitas

```
public  boolean equalLists(List<MakeModel> one, List<MakeModel> two){
    if (one == null && two == null){
        return true;
    }
    if((one == null && two != null) || 
            one != null && two == null || 
            one.size() != two.size()){
        return false;
    }
    /*para evitar arruinar el orden de las listas originales, se hacen copias*/
    List<MakeModel> a = new ArrayList(one);
    List<MakeModel> b = new ArrayList(two);

    Collections.sort(a);
    Collections.sort(b);
    return a.equals(b);
}
```

ya que la función equals, claramente podría fallar en este caso si el orden no es el mismo.